# Colors change too fast

Tags: javascript, html

So I was making a breakout game for class and finished it, so for fun, my teacher asked before I went off for Christmas break that I make the bricks change color, and yea I did that but it's WAY too fast. He says it's fine how it is- if it was slower, or if the colors changed every time a brick was hit. Can I get some help?

```js
canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
 ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
 ballRadius = 10;
 x = canvas.width/2;
 y = canvas.height-30;
 dx = 2;
 dy = -2;
const  ballColor1 = "#0095DD";
const  ballColor2 = "#ff0000";
var ballColor = ballColor1;
 paddleHeight = 10;
 paddleWidth = 75;
 paddleX = (canvas.width-paddleWidth)/2;
 rightPressed = false;
 leftPressed = false;
const brickRowCount = 5;
const brickColumnCount = 3;
const brickWidth = 75;
const brickHeight = 20;
const brickPadding = 10;
const brickOffsetTop = 30;
const brickOffsetLeft = 30;
let score = 0;
let lives = 3;

const bricks = [];
for(let c=0; c<brickColumnCount; c++) {
  bricks[c] = [];
  for(let r=0; r<brickRowCount; r++) {
    bricks[c][r] = { x: 0, y: 0, status: 1 };
  }
}
function randBrick() {
    return "#" + ((1 << 24) * Math.random() | 0).toString(16).padStart(6, "0")
}

console.log(randBrick());

document.addEventListener("keydown", keyDownHandler, false);
document.addEventListener("keyup", keyUpHandler, false);
document.addEventListener("mousemove", mouseMoveHandler, false);
document.getElementById("startAgain").addEventListener("click", function() {
  document.location.reload();
  clearInterval(interval);
  });
      
  document.getElementById("playAgain").addEventListener("click", function() {
  document.location.reload();
  clearInterval(interval);
  
   
});
   

function keyDownHandler(e) {
    if(e.key == "Right" || e.key == "ArrowRight") {
        rightPressed = true;
    }
    else if(e.key == "Left" || e.key == "ArrowLeft") {
        leftPressed = true;
    }
}

function keyUpHandler(e) {
    if(e.key == "Right" || e.key == "ArrowRight") {
        rightPressed = false;
    }
    else if(e.key == "Left" || e.key == "ArrowLeft") {
        leftPressed = false;
    }
}

function mouseMoveHandler(e) {
  const relativeX = e.clientX - canvas.offsetLeft;
  if(relativeX > 0 && relativeX < canvas.width) {
    paddleX = relativeX - paddleWidth/2;
  }
}
function collisionDetection() {
  for(let c=0; c<brickColumnCount; c++) {
    for(let r=0; r<brickRowCount; r++) {
      const b = bricks[c][r];
      if(b.status == 1) {
        if(x > b.x && x < b.x+brickWidth && y > b.y && y < b.y+brickHeight) {
          dy = -dy;
          b.status = 0;
          score++;
          if(score == brickRowCount*brickColumnCount) {
            document.getElementById('gameWin').style.display = 'block';
            clearInterval(interval); 
            randBrick();
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

      
function drawBall() {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(x, y, ballRadius, 0, Math.PI*2);
  ctx.fillStyle = ballColor;
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.closePath();
}
function drawPaddle() {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.rect(paddleX, canvas.height-paddleHeight, paddleWidth, paddleHeight);
  ctx.fillStyle = "#0095DD";
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.closePath();
}


function drawBricks() {
  for(let c=0; c<brickColumnCount; c++) {
    for(let r=0; r<brickRowCount; r++) {
      if(bricks[c][r].status == 1) {
        const brickX = (r*(brickWidth+brickPadding))+brickOffsetLeft;
        const brickY = (c*(brickHeight+brickPadding))+brickOffsetTop;
        bricks[c][r].x = brickX;
        bricks[c][r].y = brickY;
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.rect(brickX, brickY, brickWidth, brickHeight);
        ctx.fillStyle = "#" + ((1 << 24) * Math.random() | 0).toString(16).padStart(6, "0");
        ctx.fill();
        ctx.closePath();
        
      }
    }
  }
}
function drawScore() {
  ctx.font = "16px Arial";
  ctx.fillStyle = "#0095DD";
  ctx.fillText("Score: "+score, 8, 20);
}
function drawLives() {
  ctx.font = "16px Arial";
  ctx.fillStyle = "#0095DD";
  ctx.fillText("Lives: "+lives, canvas.width-65, 20);
}

function draw() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  drawBall();
  drawBricks();
  drawPaddle();
  drawScore();
  drawLives();
  collisionDetection();

  if(x + dx > canvas.width-ballRadius || x + dx < ballRadius) {
    dx = -dx; 

    if (ballColor == ballColor1) {
      ballColor = ballColor2; 
    } else {
      ballColor = ballColor1;
    }
      
  }
  if(y + dy < ballRadius) {
    dy = -dy;
    
       if (ballColor == ballColor1) {
      ballColor = ballColor2; 
    } else {
      ballColor = ballColor1;
    }
    
  }
  else if(y + dy > canvas.height-ballRadius) {
    if(x > paddleX && x < paddleX + paddleWidth) {
      dy = -dy;
    }
    else {
      lives--;
      if(!lives) {
       document.getElementById('gameOver').style.display = 'block';
    clearInterval(interval);
      }
      else {
        x = canvas.width/2;
        y = canvas.height-30;
        dx = 3;
        dy = -3;
        paddleX = (canvas.width-paddleWidth)/2;
      }
    }
  }

  
  if(rightPressed && paddleX < canvas.width-paddleWidth) {
    paddleX += 7;
  }
  else if(leftPressed && paddleX > 0) {
    paddleX -= 7;
  }

  x += dx;
  y += dy;
  
  requestAnimationFrame(draw);
      }

draw();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Breakout</title>
   
    
    <style>
      
      * {
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
       
      }
      canvas {
        background: #eee;
        display: block;
        margin: 0 auto;
        border: 5px solid red;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>

    
    <canvas id="myCanvas" width="480" height="320"></canvas>
    
    <div id="gameOver" style="display: none; position: absolute; top: 50px; left: 50px; width: 200px;">
<h1>Game Over!</h1>
<button id="startAgain">Try Again?</button>
</div>
    
    <div id="gameWin" style="display: none; position: absolute; top: 50px; left: 50px; width: 200px;">
<h1>You Win!</h1>
<button id="playAgain">Play Again?</button>
</div>

    <script src=breakoutCode.js></script>

     </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Collision detection could return true if a collision happened.  You could use that to determine whether to switch colours.

Answer (score 2):

You're changing the color on every block draw. The `Math.random()` is getting called on every draw to the canvas thus that means it's changing every block's color on each draw.

Possible solutions:

- Save the colors in an array + a the time you want to change them
- Save the colors in an array and change them randomly
- Don't re-draw the blocks on every re-draw (better for performance)

Here's one possible solution that stores the colors in an array and changes them randomly:

```js
let blkColors = []
function drawBricks() {
  for(let c=0; c<brickColumnCount; c++) {
    for(let r=0; r<brickRowCount; r++) {
      if(bricks[c][r].status == 1) {
        const brickX = (r*(brickWidth+brickPadding))+brickOffsetLeft;
        const brickY = (c*(brickHeight+brickPadding))+brickOffsetTop;
        bricks[c][r].x = brickX;
        bricks[c][r].y = brickY;
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.rect(brickX, brickY, brickWidth, brickHeight);
        if (!blkColors[c] || !blkColors[c][r] || Math.random() > 0.97) { // new color
            if (!blkColors[c])
            blkColors[c] = [];
            ctx.fillStyle = blkColors[c][r] = "#" + ((1 << 24) * Math.random() | 0).toString(16).padStart(6, "0");
        } else {
            ctx.fillStyle = blkColors[c][r];
        }
        ctx.fill();
        ctx.closePath();
        
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[On JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xr7Lbuzw/10/)